# Can I generate a dropdwon list without garbage code and bindings?

Tags: angularjs

I want to generate a drop down list, which I will use on different places by cloning the html. Is it possible to generate the dropdown code without the bindings and garbage code like ng-option etc?

If I generate the dropdown list using the code like

```
<select ng-model="userGroups" ng-options="grp.groupId as grp.groupName for grp in groups" class="form-control">
                        </select>
```

and then clone this select using jquery, will the bindings will be copied too?

Comment: how is `ng-option` "garbage code"?

Comment: Mixing angular and jquery like that isn't a good idea.. let only one of them handle the generation of DOM ...

Comment: @Alp: garbage means I just want to generate the DOM content without the extra attributes as I dont need bindings on page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to reuse template code. In that case you need to ensure that there is a `groups` object in your current scope which hold all the options for the select.

You could also wrap it in a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to dynamically assign a model to the select. That could look like this:

```
<my-select ng-model="userGroups" my-options="groups" />
```

As Bixi already said: do not mix angular with jquery when it comes to DOM manipulation. It will cause you problems on all fronts.

Comment: ng-include go for a url, what if I just want some html code to clone that is on same page?

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache
You can embed the included HTML in a special <script> tag